# Access network shares on diferent subnet

Tags: windows, networking, subnet, shares

I have two computers on my domain on different subnets, one in 10.100.176.x and other on 10.100.54.x. On the first one I can see the in explorer other network shares from 10.100.170.x to 10.100.178.x but although I can ping the second computer I can't see the shares and if I try to map anything I get error 53 network path not found. All the computers have the same configurations regarding network discovery and networking. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Network browsing relies on broadcast traffic and broadcast traffic doesn't cross subnet boundaries. That being said, accessing the shares on another computer isn't dependent upon network browsing so I suspect your problem is either: `A.` A name resolution problem. or `B.` A problem with routing, in that the two subnets don't have connectivity to each other via a router.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I can ping the the hostname so A is no right. Maybe it's B

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a firewall/routing issue. You need to find out which port your particular network shares are running and make sure traffic from one subnet is allowed to the other on that particular port. The shortcut would be to allow any traffic bi-directionally between the two subnets on your firewall/router. The long way would be to find out which ports are needed for the particular network services that are sharing the files and to open that.

Also, there might be another reason why those subnets were created to segment the networks, and if there are security precautions that should be taken.

Hope this helps!

-Byron

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a firewall issue, since you seem to have routing and DNS resolution working fine.

Windows file shares use SMB (TCP port 445); make sure this traffic is allowed between the two subnets.
Also check Windows Firewall on all involved machines.